# How to edit title on Edit post pages?

Tags: title, post-editor

The `<title`> tag in pages for post edit is `Edit Post < Site name — WordPress`. I want to change it to `Edit Post < Site name – The title of the post in editing`. Is this possible? Where can I locate the header of this page? Apparently it cannot be in the theme.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code instead on your functions.php, this will change the post and product title to the post or product that is being edit:

```
add_filter('admin_title', 'my_admin_title', 10, 2);
function my_admin_title($admin_title, $title)
{
        global $post, $action;
        if ( isset($post->post_title) and $action == 'edit' ){
        return 'Edit < '.$post->post_title.' - '.get_bloginfo('name');
        } else {
            return $title .' - ' .get_bloginfo('name');
        }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Do you know why the code doesn't work when put it in the child theme?